# Ansible task that ends all plays defined in playbook yaml file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

To start with I am using:

```
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.3]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ansible/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/ansible/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.6 (main, Feb  7 2024, 22:18:53) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17)] (/usr/local/bin/python3.11)
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True
```

And I have an Ansible role that I use in 2 different plays in one playbook `transfer-files.yml` as such:

```
- name: CMS - Transfer CSV files 1
  become: true
  hosts: host1
  roles:
    - { role: transfer_files, TRANSFER_FILES_MODE: "cms" }

- name: COMMERCE - Transfer CSV files 2
  become: true
  hosts: host2
  roles:
    - { role: transfer_files, TRANSFER_FILES_MODE: "commerce" }
```

In my role I use the TRANSFER_FILES_MODE to decide which tasks get executed `cms.yml` or `commerce.yml`. In `cms.yml` I have the following task:

```
...

- name: If directory is empty end the play silently
  ansible.builtin.meta: end_play
  when: files_found.matched < 1

...
```

So with all this said when my play gets to this task in `cms.yml` and the directory is empty it nicely ends the first play but it still executes the second play.

Is there something I can do to end all executions of all plays listed in a playbook in one task?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, because Ansible runs the plays sequentially and the next play knows nothing about the previous one.

But you can set some fact before that meta task, delegate it to `localhost`, and use `include_role` with a corresponding `when` condition that checks `hostvars.localhost.<your_fact>` on all the subsequent plays.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to terminate a playbook gracefully. Only `end_host` and `end_play` are available in the module [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html). The option `end_playbook` is missing. As a consequence, it's up to you to share the termination flag among all hosts.

- The solution is trivial if the flag (in this case the variable *terminate*) is created in a single host play. For example, delegate the variable to *localhost* in the first play and test it in all consequent plays

```yaml
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: play 1 running ...
    - set_fact:
        terminate: true
      when: files_found|d(1)|int < 1
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

 hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
      when: hostvars.localhost.terminate|d(false)
    - debug:
        msg: play 2 running ...

- hosts: host3
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
      when: hostvars.localhost.terminate|d(false)
    - debug:
        msg: play 3 running ...
```

- The situation will be more complicated if there are more hosts in the plays and any of them can set the termination flag. In this case, test all of them

```yaml
    - meta: end_play
      when: hostvars|json_query('*.terminate')|length > 0
```

This solution benefits from the fact that *hostvars* of all hosts in the inventory (yes, in the inventory, not only the hosts in a playbook) are available across the whole playbook. This makes the termination condition rather fragile.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host11
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: play 1 running ...
    - set_fact:
        terminate: true
      when: inventory_hostname == 'host1'

- hosts: host2,host12
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.terminate') }}"
        - meta: end_play
          when: hostvars|json_query('*.terminate')|length > 0
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: play 2 running ...

- hosts: host3,host13
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.terminate') }}"
        - meta: end_play
          when: hostvars|json_query('*.terminate')|length > 0
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: play 3 running ...
```